# problema con mi url a usar htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo un sistema el cual mediante la url detecto que cliente es y segun eso leo un php con su informacion y esto cambia segun el requerimiento; por ejemplo:

```
http://miweb.com/cliente1/ me muestra variables de /cliente/cliente1.php
http://miweb.com/cliente2/ me muestra variables de /cliente/cliente2.php
```

sin embargo la carpeta cliente1 o cliente2 no existe yo consigo acceso mediante htaccess con esto:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_+]+)/?$ index.php?id__cliente=$1 [L]
```

hasta alli me funciona perfecto; el problema esta en el momento de ejecutar directamente un archivo php que no sea index.php por ejemplo si quiero acceder a esta url:

```
http://miweb.com/cliente2/box.php
```

obviamente me muestra que el archivo no existe, y tengo entendido que para solucionarlo tengo que pasar todas mis url por htaccess y redireccionarlas directamente pero abria alguna forma de poner que esto sea variante ? ya que yo quisiera poder crear php en la raiz sin preocuparme que tengo que editar mi htaccess.

Yo intente con esto pero me retorna que el archivo no existe:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_+]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_+]+).php?$ $2 [L]
```

Pero no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto mejor (ponla antes de la otra rule):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_+]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_+]+).php?$ $2.php [L]
```

**Recomendación:**

Te iran saliendo cada vez más casos y seguirás agregando rules a tu `.htaccess` hasta convertirlo en infumable.

Te recomiendo que centralices todo en el **index.php** de tu raíz y captures la URL con esto:

```
$url   = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

Y a partir de aquí *filtres* esa variable y hagas y deshagas lo que necesites con **include/require** segun requieras en lugar de modificar el `.htaccess`.
Creo que te será más práctico en el futuro seguramente.

En este caso tu `.htaccess` podria quedar así:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php [L]
```

y el **index.php** seria el que filtraria la url tal como he explicado anttes.